# Android: trying to get rid of return after enter key is press on TextView

Tags: android

I have code that removes the keyboard when enter is pressed. Now the issue is that the EditView has a new line inserted.  I tried to get the text from the textview and remove any cartrige returns.  But it does not work.

here is the code:

```
mUserName.setOnEditorActionListener(
    new android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
    {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
        {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mUserName.getWindowToken(), 0);

            CharSequence c=v.getText();
            String h= c.toString();
            v.setText(h.replaceAll("\n",""));   

            return false;
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict the input to only one line, use

```
mUserName.setLines(1);
mUserName.setMaxLines(1);
```

Or, **`mUserName.setSingleLine(true);`**

Comment: The [`singleLine` attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine) is deprecated.

Comment: @Eric : Oh, was not aware of that. But, anyway, it still does the job. :D

Comment: Yes it's deprecated, but on some 2.1 and 2.2 phones, if you don't set singleLine=true, the TextView does not behave correctly. Strange, but it's android...

Comment: @ol_v_er Interesting. `android:lines` was added in API 1, I'd think it should function in all versions. Good to know.

Comment: Hi, the mUserName.setLines(1); mUserName.setMaxLines(1); did not work, but setSingleLine did, maybe ist the api version issue?

Comment: Yes, as @ol_v_er has already mentioned that sometimes it does not work properly if setSingleLine is not given. I am glad it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I wouldn't rely on `OnEditorActionListener`. There are better methods to do what you're looking for. I would suggest three things you could do:

- Set the IME options of the field.
- Set line count to 1.
- Use a `TextWatcher` instead. (Optional, shouldn't be required)

To set the [IME options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html) (get rid of the Enter button), use the following:

```
mUserName.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE);
```

Next, you can force the line count to be 1:

```
mUserName.setLines(1);
mUserName.setMaxLines(1);
```

If neither of these work (which they should), you can use a `TextWatcher` to remove the newlines instead:

```
mUserName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // Here, CHECK if it contains \r OR \n, then replaceAll
        // Checking is very important so you do not get an infinite loop
        if (s.toString().contains("\r") || s.toString().contains("\n")) {
            s = s.replaceAll("[\r|\n]", "");
            mUserName.setText(s);
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // Nothing
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Nothing
    }
});
```

You may have to play with this setup a bit, I haven't tested the `replaceAll` regex or run the code myself, but it's definitely a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm still learning android did not know about ontextchange -Ted